# Como puedo leer la configuración del appservice a un webjob

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-storage

Estoy trabajando con Azure Web Job, pero para configurar la cadena de conexión lo hago en un archivo aparte, yo quiero que cuando el webjob este corriendo en azure, lea la misma cadena de conexión del appservice, solo imagina que tengo que hacer 20 webjobs, lo mejor es automatizar y que todos lean la misma cadena de conexión, tanto para la BD como para AzureStorage

Comment: Si, como dije, BD o una cadena de conexión de Azure Storage

Comment: Pero para automatizar se supone que podrias usar una tool de DevOps que tome el codigo del GitHub (o el repo de codigo que uses) lo compile y lo publique em Azure, asi se automatiza, y no cambiando la configuracion. La idea de automatizar es usa  una tool para el continuous delivery, si es que vas a tener muchos webjob

Comment: un comentarios, porque estas creando webjob en lugar de usar Azure Functions? con las function puedes hacer lo mismo que los webjobs y son mas modernos

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

una manera de hacerlo es empleando `Azure Key Vault` para almacenar esas credenciales y que todos tus WebJobs o Functions lean desde ese sitio. [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/key-vault/) tienes un enlace a la documentación.

Un ejemplo de cómo iniciar un host web dado su archivo `Program.cs` es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace key_vault_dotnet_core_quickstart
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
           WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
               {
                   var keyVaultEndpoint = GetKeyVaultEndpoint();
                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                   {
                       var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                       var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                           new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                               azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                       builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
                           keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                   }
               }
            ).UseStartup<Startup>()
             .Build();

        private static string GetKeyVaultEndpoint() => "https://<YourKeyVaultName>.vault.azure.net";
    }
}
```

Como puedes observar, se emplea el método de extensión `ConfigureAppConfiguration` para que se lea la configuración desde tu Key Vault. 
Luego, en tu Controller o donde sea que uses tu inyección de dependencias puedes usar el  `IConfiguration` para devolver el valor de tu Secreto.

En este caso un ejemplo sería

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace key_vault_dotnet_core_quickstart.Pages
{
    public class AboutModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public AboutModel(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration = null;

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = "My key val = " + _configuration["AppSecret"];
        }
    }
}
```

Revisa ejemplos que hay en `https://github.com/Azure-Samples`. en este caso mi respuesta está basada en `https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-dotnet-core-quickstart`